# MVC table highlight rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.Net MVC table that I need to highlight certain rows in it when it loads.  If the type = chargeback or retroactive then I need to highlight that row.  I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  I guess you would do the highlighting with Javascript, but how do I check the type in the table and then highlight it?

Here's my table:

```
<table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Order No.</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Reason</th>
                                    <th>Fill Date</th>
                                    <th>Due Date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var linkedOrder in order.LinkedOrders)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @if (@linkedOrder.Type == "Spiff")
                                            {
                                                <a onclick="DisplayReceipt('@linkedOrder.OrderNo')">@linkedOrder.OrderNo</a>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                @linkedOrder.OrderNo
                                            }

                                        </td>
                                        <td>@linkedOrder.Type</td>
                                        <td>@linkedOrder.Price.ToString("C")</td>
                                        <td>@linkedOrder.Reason</td>
                                        <td>@(linkedOrder.FillDate == null ? "--" : linkedOrder.FillDate.Value.ToShortDateString())</td>
                                        <td>@(linkedOrder.DueDate == null ? "--" : linkedOrder.DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString())</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need javascript, you can do it via razor like below

```
<tr @if (linkedOrder.Type == "chargeback") { <text> style="background-color:silver;" </text>  }>
```

Replace your `<tr>` in the body with this mark up

Comment: You would ideally do this by setting the `class` value rather than using an inline style.  @hutchonoid's answer shows how to do this in a more succinct and maintainable manner.

Answer (score 2):

A razor/css solution could be:

```
 ...
 <tr class="@linkedOrder.Type">
       <td> ...
```

Add the css:

```
tr.chargeback {
   background-color: red;
}

tr.retroactive {
   background-color: green;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bt7z4kpL/)